# Having issue with menu bar being persistent on my web page. Possible z-index and overlay issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-development-server

Here is my CSS and HTML Code I am currently having issues with the menu bar being persistent on the whole page. Currently I would like to change the z-index of the overlay to 1, but that makes both the "MORE INFO" and the three bottom link buttons not clickable. I have tried tweaking the z-index value in the .overlay() from 1 to 0 and that allows me to click on the more info button, but in doing so that messes up everything else because the menu bar is still able to be hovered when in the main page.

I am not sure what is causing this issue, but it seems to be a z-index issue or an opacity issue. I am posting my code on here to ask for help, this is for a project for school and I do not know what could be causing this issue.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;

}


.hero-section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.hero-logo {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Cosi Azure";
  font-style: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin: 2em;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-toggle ion-icon {
  font-style: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #8c1f1f;
  z-index: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  
  
  
}

.overlay ion-icon {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  margin: 2em;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  

}

.overlay ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1;

}

.overlay ul li {
  font-size: 84px;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .overlay ul li {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}

.overlay ul li a {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.media {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 2em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.media ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.media ul li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.media ul li a {
  color: white;
}

.view-photos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.view-photos a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-style: italic;
}

.view-photos a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.hero-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
}

.hero-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.hero-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-title h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .hero-title .letter {
    font-size: 24px !important;
  }
}

.hero-title .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}

.about-section {
  padding: 120px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.about-section h1 {
  font-size: 84px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 1;
}

.about-section h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  z-index: 1;
}

.about-link {
  margin: 50px 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.about-link a {
  color: black;
  padding: 18px 36px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  z-index: 1;

}

.about-link a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

.project-section {
  background: #0f0f0f;
  padding-top: 120px;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
}

.project-section h1 {
  font-size: 84px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

.project-section p {
  color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.project-heading {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}

.project-section ion-icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 148px;
}

.project-img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 80vh;
}

.project {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.social-media {
  padding: 0 0;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.social-media h1 {
  font-size: 84px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.social-media h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.social-icons {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.social-icons ul {
  margin: 80px 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.social-icons ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.social-icons ul li a {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Cormorant";
  font-size: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="author" content="ig: @andree_h " />
    <title>PORTFOLIO FOR HECTOR COUZIN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- ANIMEJS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

    <!-- GSAP -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- IONICONS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

    <!-- SCROLL REVEAL ANIMATIONS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/daneden/animate.css/v3.1.0/animate.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/matthieua/WOW/1.0.1/dist/wow.min.js"></script>

    <!-- SIMPLE PARALLAX -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-parallax-js@5.0.2/dist/simpleParallax.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- HERO SECTION -->
    <a name="home"></a>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <section class="hero-section">
        <!-- LOGO -->
        <div class="hero-logo">
          HC
        </div>

        <!-- TOGGLE BUTTON -->
        <div class="menu-toggle">
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </div>

        <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS -->
        <div class="media">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/heckportflio"><ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/andree_h/"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/andree10141"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- VIEW PHOTOS LINK -->
        <div class="view-photos">
          <a href="#projects">view photos</a>
        </div>

        <!-- HERO-IMAGE -->
        <div class="hero-img">
          <img src="hero-bg.jpg" class="hero-img-parallax" />
        </div>

        <!-- HERO-TITLE -->
        <div class="hero-title">
          <h1>Hector Couzin</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="close-btn">
            <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <a name="about"></a>
      <section class="about-section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="about-heading col-lg-6">
              <h1 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">About</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="about-content col-lg-6">
              <h3 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Nesciunt esse autem hic!
              </h3>
              <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore
                asperiores voluptates, tenetur incidunt libero at aut culpa
                atque ab repellat deserunt ullam eaque eum.
              </p>
              <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Recusandae quod magnam sequi enim quo laudantium soluta
                blanditiis quia consectetur, expedita temporibus, cum officiis
                totam doloremque unde harum dolor, veritatis quae sunt!
                Repellendus, qui. Corporis voluptas optio doloribus, at quidem
                cumque?
              </p>
              <div class="about-link wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                <a href="#contact">MORE INFO</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <a name="projects"></a>
      <section class="project-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="arrow-down">
                  <ion-icon
                    name="arrow-down"
                    class="wow fadeInUp"
                    data-wow-delay="0.2s"
                  ></ion-icon>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="project-heading col-lg-6">
                <h1 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">CAPTURES</h1>
                <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                  Aliquam quaerat sunt architecto veritatis suscipit nostrum
                  amet dicta ut, nobis modi.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="projects">
            <div class="row project-row">
              <div class="project project-1 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-1.jpg"
                  class="project-1-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="project project-2 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-2.jpg"
                  class="project-2-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row project-row">
              <div class="project project-3 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-3.jpg"
                  class="project-3-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="project project-4 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-4.jpg"
                  class="project-4-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row project-row">
              <div class="project project-5 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-5.jpg"
                  class="project-5-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="project project-6 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-6.jpg"
                  class="project-6-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="project project-6 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-6.jpg"
                  class="project-6-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="project project-6 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-6.jpg"
                  class="project-6-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>
                <!-- COPY THIS TO ADD MORE PHOTOS
                 <div class="project project-6 col-lg-6">
                <img
                  src="project-6.jpg"
                  class="project-6-img project-img img-responsive fit-image"
                />
              </div>-->

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <a name="contact"></a>
      <section class="social-media">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="sm-heading col-lg-6">
              <h1 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">Reach out</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sm-content col-lg-6">
              <h3 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                couzinhector@gmail.com
              </h3>
              <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Incidunt quo similique eaque ducimus quibusdam, dolorum
                reprehenderit cumque. Dolorem, placeat. Similique!
              </p>
              <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Distinctio ducimus natus hic dolorem voluptate dolore officiis
                neque aperiam similique! Obcaecati vel et atque nesciunt quia
                quis expedita nulla, cum autem eius itaque incidunt, ut delectus
                vitae. Cupiditate minima debitis aliquam!
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
            <div class="social-icons">
              <ul>
                <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.7s">
                  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/heckportflio/">linkedin</a>
                </li>
                <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/andree_h/">instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/andree10141">twitter</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>



    <!-- Emmbeded Javascript-->
    <script>
      new WOW().init();

      var textWrapper = document.querySelector(".hero-title");
      textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
        /\S/g,
        "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
      );
      $(document).ready(function() {
        anime.timeline({ loop: false }).add({
          targets: ".hero-title .letter",
          translateY: [120, 0],
          translateZ: 0,
          opacity: [0, 1],
          easing: "easeOutExpo",
          duration: 1400,
          delay: (el, i) => 500 + 40 * i
        });
      });

      var t1 = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });

      TweenMax.from(".hero-logo", 2, {
        y: 20,
        opacity: 0,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
        delay: .1
      });

      TweenMax.from(".menu-toggle", 2, {
        y: 20,
        opacity: 0,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
        delay: .1
      });

      TweenMax.from(".view-photos", 2, {
        y: 20,
        opacity: 0,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
        delay: .1
      });

      TweenMax.staggerFrom(
        ".media ul li",
        2,
        {
          y: 20,
          opacity: 0,
          ease: Expo.easeInOut,
          delay: .1
        },
        0.1
      );

      t1.to(".overlay", 1, {
        opacity: 1,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut
      });

      t1.to(".view-photos, .media", 1, {
        opacity: 0,
        ease: Expo.easeInOut
      });

      t1.staggerFrom(
        ".menu ul li",
        1,
        { y: 100, opacity: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut },
        0.1
      );
    
      t1.reverse();
      $(document).on("click", ".menu-toggle", function() {
        t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
      });

      $(document).on("click", ".close-btn", function() {
        t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
      });

      t1.reverse();
      $(document).on("click", "li", function() {
        t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
      });

      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("hero-img-parallax");
      new simpleParallax(image, {
        scale: 1.8
      });

      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("project-1-img");
      new simpleParallax(image, {
        scale: 1.8
      });

      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("project-2-img");
      new simpleParallax(image, {
        scale: 1.8
      });

      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("project-3-img");
      new simpleParallax(image, {
        scale: 1.8
      });

      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("project-4-img");
      new simpleParallax(image, {
        scale: 1.8
      });

      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("project-5-img");
      new simpleParallax(image, {
        scale: 1.8
      });

      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("project-6-img");
      new simpleParallax(image, {
        scale: 1.8
      });

      /* Select all links with hashes*/
      $('a[href*="#"]')
        // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
        .not('[href="#"]')
        .not('[href="#0"]')
        .click(function(event) {
          // On-page links
          if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") ==
              this.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") &&
            location.hostname == this.hostname
          ) {
            // Figure out element to scroll to
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length
              ? target
              : $("[name=" + this.hash.slice(1) + "]");
            // Does a scroll target exist?
            if (target.length) {
              // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
              event.preventDefault();
              $("html, body").animate(
                {
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                },
                1000,
                function() {
                  // Callback after animation
                  // Must change focus!
                  var $target = $(target);
                  $target.focus();
                  if ($target.is(":focus")) {
                    // Checking if the target was focused
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    $target.attr("tabindex", "-1"); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                    $target.focus(); // Set focus again
                  }
                }
              );
            }
          }
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to toggle the `z-index` with JS

Comment: I have disabled the javascript to see what is causing the problem and the problem is still persistent on the page where the menu is still able to hover even though the javascript for the menu to come out is disabled.